# Node - Cross Plattform compilation - PKG

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, binary, cross-platform

I am currently trying to compile a node app for macos using pkg:

https://github.com/zeit/pkg

First of all my setup:

```
macos 10.14.5 (Mojave)
node -v => v11.4.0
npm -v => 6.4.1
pkg -v => 4.4.0
```

My first try:

```
pkg index.js -t node11-mac-x64 --output dist/app-mac
```

Resulted in:

```
> pkg@4.4.0
> Error! No available node version satisfies 'node11'
```

Thats why i switched to:

```
pkg index.js -t node10-mac-x64 --output dist/app-mac
```

Result:

```
> pkg@4.4.0
> Warning
  Cannot include addon %1 into executable.
  The addon must be distributed with executable as %2.
  node_modules/sha3/build/Release/sha3.node
  path-to-executable/sha3.node
> Warning
  Cannot include addon %1 into executable.
  The addon must be distributed with executable as %2.
  node_modules/websocket/build/Release/bufferutil.node
  path-to-executable/bufferutil.node
> Warning
  Cannot include addon %1 into executable.
  The addon must be distributed with executable as %2.
  node_modules/websocket/build/Release/validation.node
  path-to-executable/validation.node
> Warning
  Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file /snapshot/app/node_modules/brotli/build/encode.js
```

But the executable has been generated, so i tried to run it:

```
./app-mac
```

Which resulted in the total disaster:

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1185
      throw error;
      ^

Error: File '/**/app/node_modules/linebreak/src/classes.trie' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.
    at error_ENOENT (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:429:17)
    at readFileFromSnapshot (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:657:29)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:700:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/app/node_modules/linebreak/src/linebreaker.js:15:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/app/node_modules/linebreak/src/linebreaker.js:161:4)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1261:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:710:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

I already read every single issue on github related to *pkg* and tried various configurations, but none of them helped...

Can anybody please help?
Trying to solve this issue for days now..

Thanks and greetings!

Is there no way i can package my application?

**Update: In github they say, i have to include the .node files in the build process... but how do i do that?**

Comment: Their readme is pretty clear: "Native addons (.node files) use is supported, but packaging .node files inside the executable is not resolved yet. You have to deploy native addons used by your project to the same directory as the executable."

Comment: yea pretty clear... :/ is there any *official* workaround? like how to configure package.json pkg ?

Comment: no idea, but you can just copy them to where it says.

Comment: ok but i didnt get where to copy them... do i have to copy *node_modules/sha3/build/Release/sha3.node* into the root directory and then run pkg again?

Comment: from what it says, I think you have to copy them to `dist/app-mac` and then re-run the app. I have no experience with pkg, just guessing here.

Comment: well basically i am done ?! i can not build my app and thats it ? none of the suggestions worked..

Comment: I'd try to post an issue in their github.

Comment: there are already arund 400 open issues

Comment: so is there no way i can build my executable? :(

Answer (score 1):

I am too facing many problems using `pkg`. But I think you should change that `node10-mac-x64` to `node14-mac-x64`. That worked for me **on Windows**.

And the thing you were talking about getting the `.node` files, that's still a big problem. I tried to copy those with my `.exe` file but it didn't work.

Comment: This also works for me on Mac M1.